# How to make a Discord bot add a role when a user joins?

Tags: python, discord.py

[ SOLVED ]
The below code works, I had just not put the 'Bot' role high enough in the roles tab. Make sure to check that it is higher than the role you are trying to give.

Basically, I am trying to get my Discord bot to add a role to a user when they join the guild. I have looked it up, but all of them seem to be outdated. My current code looks like this:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    role = discord.utils.get(getGuild().roles, name='ExampleRole')
    await member.add_roles(role)
```

And the getGuild method looks like this:

```
def getGuild():
for guild in client.guilds:
    if guild.name == GUILD_NAME:
        return guild;
```

However, this prints an error, which looks like this:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "DiscordBot.py", line 36, in on_member_join
    await member.add_roles(role)
  File "discord\member.py", line 777, in add_roles
    await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)
  File "discord\http.py", line 248, in request
    raise Forbidden(r, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

Obviously I removed the file path, but kept the file names.
I'm using the latest Discord.py, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you enabled intents? Or is the bot role perhaps lower than the role it is trying to apply? It's trying, to apply the role, but is missing the permission.

Comment: @AbdurJ :D that was the issue! I thought I had put the 'Bot' role above the rest, but it turned out I hadn't saved the changes! TYSM!